# Is it safe to replace specific mods in a modpack (Tekkit-Lite)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I read Tekki-Lite won't be updated, but i would like to use a newer version of BuildCraft where the Builder was re-enabled. Is it safe to replace the BuildCraft version by hand? Will the technik Launcher override my replacement and downgrade? Is there any risk to my world? What about adding other mods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when playing minecraft with mods, the mods version are unique to the version you are playing for example: if your playing in minecraft 1.4.7 then the mods are 1.4.7 compatible. meaning you can't put a 1.7.2 buildcraft version in there because it will black screen your game when launching.
also when adding/replacing a mod delete the older version before adding the new version of the mod in.

if you are updating a modpack create a save of your .Minecraft folder for tekkit so if anything goes wrong your have a go to save.

Answer (score 0):

If the newer version of BuildCraft is compatible with Minecraft 1.4.7, then yes, you can safely replace it. Just make sure you delete the old Buildcraft version first.

Answer (score -3):

No it is not after you do that a picture will pop up saying You can not play minecraft anymore and after that it deletes your minecraft profile.